# Java Spring - Error starting ApplicationContext. Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

My app is a Spring MVC Application with PostgreSQL database. I'm using Maven, and STS IDE.

I was trying to resolve this problem to my own, but i have to surrender. If you have some time, please look at this code:

Spring Application

```
package com.example.dv;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringDataViewerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringDataViewerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

WebController

```
package com.example.controller;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

    import com.example.model.Seria;
    import com.example.repo.*;

    @RestController
    public class WebController {
        @Autowired
        SeriaRepository repo;

        @RequestMapping("/findall")
        public List<Seria> findAll()
        {
            List<Seria> result = new ArrayList<Seria>();

            for(Seria s : repo.findAll())
            {
                result.add(s);
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
```

My Entity class

```
package com.example.model;


import java.time.*;
import java.util.UUID;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="serie")
public class Seria {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String file;
    private UUID cassid;
    private Long categoryid;
    private LocalDate datefrom;
    private int frequency;
    private Long[] markers;
    private String unit;
    private String feed;
    private Long userid;
    private LocalDateTime createdate;
    private LocalDateTime changedate;

    protected Seria() {}

    public Seria(Long id, String name, String file, UUID cassid, Long categoryid, LocalDate datefrom, int frequency, Long[] markers, String unit, String feed, Long userid, LocalDateTime createdate, LocalDateTime changedate)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.file = file;
        this.cassid = cassid;
        this.categoryid = categoryid;
        this.datefrom = datefrom;
        this.frequency = frequency;
        this.markers = markers;
        this.unit = unit;
        this.feed = feed;
        this.userid = userid;
        this.createdate = createdate;
        this.changedate = changedate;
    }

    public void setId(Long Id)
    {
        id = Id;
    }
    public Long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setName(String Name)
    {
        name = Name;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setFile(String File)
    {
        file = File;
    }
    public String getFile()
    {
        return file;
    }

    public void setCassid(UUID Cassid)
    {
        cassid = Cassid;
    }
    public UUID getCassid()
    {
        return cassid;
    }

    public void setCategoryid(Long Categoryid)
    {
        categoryid = Categoryid;
    }
    public Long getCategoryid()
    {
        return categoryid;
    }

    public void setDatefrom(LocalDate Datefrom)
    {
        datefrom = Datefrom;
    }
    public LocalDate getDatefrom()
    {
        return datefrom;
    }

    public void setFrequency(int Frequency)
    {
        frequency = Frequency;
    }
    public int getFrequency()
    {
        return frequency;
    }

    public void setMarkers(Long[] Markers)
    {
        markers = Markers;
    }
    public Long[] getMarkers()
    {
        return markers;
    }

    public void setUnit(String Unit)
    {
        unit = Unit;
    }
    public String getUnit()
    {
        return unit;
    }

    public void setFeed(String Feed)
    {
        feed = Feed;
    }
    public String getFeed()
    {
        return feed;
    }

    public void setUserid(Long Userid)
    {
        userid = Userid;
    }
    public Long getUserid()
    {
        return userid;
    }

    public void setCreatedate(LocalDateTime Createdate)
    {
        createdate = Createdate;
    }
    public LocalDateTime getCreatedate()
    {
        return createdate;
    }

    public void setChangedate(LocalDateTime Changeedate)
    {
        changedate = Changeedate;
    }
    public LocalDateTime getChangedate()
    {
        return changedate;
    }


}
```

DAO class

```
package com.example.repo;


import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.example.model.*;

public interface SeriaRepository extends CrudRepository<Seria, Long>{

}
```

POM.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>pl.pawelmalysz</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringDataViewer</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>SpringDataViewer</name>
    <description>Spring boot data viewer</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>10</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

I was trying to fix this by deleting hibernate folders in maven directory and reinstall it, but it doesn't works.

UPDATE:

Application propeties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=post
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

Stack

```
SpringDataViewer - SpringDataViewerApplication [Spring Boot App]    
    com.example.dv.SpringDataViewerApplication at localhost:54188   
        Thread [main] (Suspended (exception BeanCreationException)) 
            ReflectionUtils.rethrowRuntimeException(Throwable) line: 322    
            SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(ConfigurableApplicationContext, Throwable, Collection<SpringBootExceptionReporter>, SpringApplicationRunListeners) line: 825 
            SpringApplication.run(String...) line: 338  
            SpringApplication.run(Class<?>[], String[]) line: 1255  
            SpringApplication.run(Class<?>, String...) line: 1243   
            SpringDataViewerApplication.main(String[]) line: 10 
    C:\Program Files\Java\jre-10.0.1\bin\javaw.exe (10 lip 2018, 12:12:45)
```

Logs after deleting .m2 maven folder and redownload it by IDE.

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.3.RELEASE)

2018-07-10 12:50:00.031  INFO 16716 --- [           main] c.e.dv.SpringDataViewerApplication       : Starting SpringDataViewerApplication on DESKTOP-0ONCQ2O with PID 16716 (C:\Users\Wolfik\Documents\workspace-sts-3.9.4.RELEASE\SpringDataViewer\target\classes started by Wolfik in C:\Users\Wolfik\Documents\workspace-sts-3.9.4.RELEASE\SpringDataViewer)
2018-07-10 12:50:00.033  INFO 16716 --- [           main] c.e.dv.SpringDataViewerApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-07-10 12:50:00.270  INFO 16716 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@524f3b3a: startup date [Tue Jul 10 12:50:00 CEST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1 (file:/C:/Users/Wolfik/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.0.7.RELEASE/spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2018-07-10 12:50:01.318  INFO 16716 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7beb6de2] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-07-10 12:50:01.566  INFO 16716 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-07-10 12:50:01.592  INFO 16716 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-07-10 12:50:01.592  INFO 16716 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.31
2018-07-10 12:50:01.597  INFO 16716 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;E:\Git\cmd;C:\Users\Wolfik\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;.]
2018-07-10 12:50:01.743  INFO 16716 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-07-10 12:50:01.743  INFO 16716 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1544 ms
2018-07-10 12:50:01.894  INFO 16716 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2018-07-10 12:50:01.898  INFO 16716 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-10 12:50:01.899  INFO 16716 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-10 12:50:01.899  INFO 16716 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-10 12:50:01.899  INFO 16716 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-10 12:50:02.053  INFO 16716 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2018-07-10 12:50:02.265  INFO 16716 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2018-07-10 12:50:02.302  INFO 16716 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-07-10 12:50:02.313  INFO 16716 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2018-07-10 12:50:02.376  INFO 16716 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.17.Final}
2018-07-10 12:50:02.378  INFO 16716 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2018-07-10 12:50:02.450  INFO 16716 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2018-07-10 12:50:02.561  INFO 16716 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
2018-07-10 12:50:02.714  INFO 16716 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl        : HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl.useContextualLobCreation(LobCreatorBuilderImpl.java:113) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl.makeLobCreatorBuilder(LobCreatorBuilderImpl.java:54) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentImpl.<init>(JdbcEnvironmentImpl.java:271) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:114) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:259) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:861) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:888) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) [spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) [spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) [spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) [spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769) [spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706) [spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583) [spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) [spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) [spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) [spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) [spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:859) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at com.example.dv.SpringDataViewerApplication.main(SpringDataViewerApplication.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Metoda org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.createClob()nie jest jeszcze obsługiwana.
    at org.postgresql.Driver.notImplemented(Driver.java:683) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar:42.2.2]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.createClob(PgConnection.java:1252) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar:42.2.2]
    ... 44 common frames omitted

2018-07-10 12:50:02.717  INFO 16716 --- [           main] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry     : HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@15986dd5
2018-07-10 12:50:02.890  INFO 16716 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-07-10 12:50:03.068  WARN 16716 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'seriaRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.example.model.Seria
2018-07-10 12:50:03.068  INFO 16716 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-07-10 12:50:03.068  INFO 16716 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2018-07-10 12:50:03.081  INFO 16716 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2018-07-10 12:50:03.083  INFO 16716 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-07-10 12:50:03.108  INFO 16716 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-07-10 12:50:03.114 ERROR 16716 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'seriaRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.example.model.Seria
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1710) ~[spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583) ~[spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:742) ~[spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at com.example.dv.SpringDataViewerApplication.main(SpringDataViewerApplication.java:13) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.example.model.Seria
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:473) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:73) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:66) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:181) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:119) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:102) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:298) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$3(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:287) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:141) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:63) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:290) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:102) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769) ~[spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706) ~[spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Can you post your stack strace ?

Comment: Post your property file and is your repository class in on same package as **SpringDataViewerApplication** ?

Comment: @mallikarjun SpringDataViewerApplication is in package com.example.dv and repo class is in com.example.repo class

Comment: @zakariaamine i updated post

Comment: @PawełMałysz as the pacages are different for config and repo you have to use @EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.repo") in config class.

Comment: @mallikarjun I did it like you wrote, but i have still the same error.

Comment: @PawełMałysz as mentioned earlier configured your entity classes too using  EntityScan [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-entity-classes) note under the code. Same for controller and all.

Comment: @mallikarjun thanks! I found this tip few minutes earlier :) You are right of course.

Comment: Move the `SpringDataViewerApplication` to `com.example` as advices by the Spring Boot Team (that way you don't need to manually enable all other features).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I solved this problem. For anyone who has similar errors, try to add an annotation in the main application "Application.java"

@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.repo")

@EntityScan("com.example.yourEntityPackage)

Comment: Instead move the `SpringDataViewerApplication` to `com.example` as advices by the Spring Boot Team (that way you don't need to manually enable all other features).

Answer (score 0):

Its a problem with maven dependencies. Go to your .m2 folder and erase de folder of javassist. Then update your maven dependencies and it's gonna work

Comment: MMmm can you try with java 8 ?

Comment: Yep.

I deleted .m2 folder, and after that i get other error in logs (look at update). Now i changed java version from 10 to 8 and have the same error like on 10(after delete .m2)

Comment: ok so you have two problems,
1) let java 8 for the moment (https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15939)
2) prefix ALL your packages with "com.example.dv"

Answer (score 0):

Not a managed type: class com.example.model.Seria
fix that please, add it to mapped classes